# Limit of trig functions

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions, exponential-function, special-functions

We have to evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\cos^x a +\sin^x a -1}{x-2}.$$

I am working on it for hours

I tried using series , replacing $\cos a$ by $t$ and $\sin a$ by $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ but not got any result

How can I start it .

Comment: L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I tried to improve your post using MathJax (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020),  [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Simon but how can we differentiate $cosa^{x}$

Comment: @akbar Does $cosa^x$ mean $(\cos a)^x$?

Comment: $(cos a)^x = (e^{ln cos a})^x = e^{x ln cos a} $.

Comment: @almagest it mean $(\cos a)^x$?

Comment: @Simon then what can we say from this

Comment: You can differentiate  $e^{x ln cos a} $ using the chain rule.

Comment: @Simon thank you , i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assume that both $\cos a, \sin a$ are positive in order to evaluate this limit. This means that $a$ is in first quadrant. Assuming that this is so, we can simply assume that $\cos a = A, \sin a = B$ where $A, B$ are fixed positive numbers with $A^{2} + B^{2} = 1$ we can put $x = 2 + h$ so that as $x \to 2$ we have $h \to 0$. Then we have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{A^{x} + B^{x} - 1}{x - 2}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{A^{2 + h} + B^{2 + h} - A^{2} - B^{2}}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{A^{2}\{\exp(h\log A) - 1\} + B^{2}\{\exp(h\log B) - 1\}}{h}\notag\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}A^{2}\log A\frac{\{\exp(h\log A) - 1\}}{h\log A} + B^{2}\log B\frac{\{\exp(h\log B) - 1\}}{h\log B}\notag\\
&= A^{2}\log A + B^{2}\log B\notag\\
&= \cos^{2}a\log\cos a + \sin^{2}a\log\sin a\notag
\end{align}